# nx doesn't show question on input prompt via readline

Tags: node.js, child-process, spawn, nrwl-nx

I'm running a CLI inside an nx monorepo via `nx run` and it seems like nx is buffering CLI output on newlines and preventing interactively answering prompts from the terminal. Here's a simple example:

Let's say I have a CLI that's written in Python or JavaScript that shows a message and then asks for input. How can I get another nodejs script to run this CLI and show me the question: `What is your name?` *without requiring a newline after the question*?

## Sample Output

```
Welcome to my CLI!
What is your name? Paul
Hi, Paul!
```

## Python Implementation

```py
print("Welcome to my CLI")
user_name = input("What is your name?")
print(f"Hi, {user_name}")
```

## TypeScript Implementation

```js
import readline from 'readline';

export const askQuestion = (query: string): Promise<string> => {
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    rl.question(query, (ans) => {
      rl.close();
      if (ans) {
        resolve(ans);
      } else {
        reject('No answer received');
      }
    });
  });
};

const main = async () => {
  console.log("Welcome to my CLI");
  const userName = await askQuestion("What is your name?");
  console.log(`Hi, ${userName}!`);
}
```

## My attempt (that fails to show the question)

```js
import * as execa from 'execa';
const main = async () => {
  await execa(cmd, args, {
    stdio: [process.stdin, process.stdout, 'pipe'],
  });
}
main()
```

### The output

```
Welcome to my CLI!
```

That's it! It will not show "What is your name?". I can type "Paul" and the program will proceed. But it will not actually show the question when run via nx. If the question has a `\n` at the end (`"What is your name?\n"`) then it will show up. But unfortunately, this CLI runner needs to work with CLIs that I don't have control over and do prompt for input without newlines.